# Parsing and serializing packets in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, protocol-buffers

I am writing network code for a project game server. I have seen rAthena C code that uses structs to build packets to communicate between client and server.

I have been accepting packets from the client and it is all in Buffer. I wanted to be able to parse what is inside that buffer.

Something like:

```
0A 00 01 00 73 73 73 73 73 73
```

If the structure of that packet is

```
length: 0A 00
id: 01 00
extra: 73 73 73 73 73 73
```

In node.js how would I parse it and if I wanted to do it the other way around like serialize it, how would I do it? Any libraries for such tasks? and what are this things called? Is it protobuf?

Also there will be 1000+ of packets that will be sent and recv (serialized and parsed) through out the code it will be very messy if I do it like:

```
if (packet.id == 1) // do stuff
if (packet.id == 2) // do stuff
// so on so forth
```

So how can this be handled?

---

A somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973201/node-js-protobuffer-buffer-lentgh-how-to-send-structured-buffer-message-trou).

Comment: I used a convert function from Buffer to String, and then I used substring to get parts of the packet. Will that work?

Comment: @MiguelRipoll could work but seems too hackish. Also working on a MMORPG needs all the performance I could get. converting Buffer to String, and substring, and converting it back to Buffer could be alittle painful. Thanks though.